Correct position of "always"
Which of the following two sentences is grammatically correct?

The train always arrives late.
The train arrives always late.

Using the logic from answers to a similar question for the word "only", it seems that if I want to emphasize the lateness of the train, the second option should be used.

The examples from the other question reveal the problem with example 2. "I eat fish only when I'm sick." vs. "I eat only fish when I'm sick.". Your example 1 says the train always arrives at a time after the expected time. But example 2, technically speaking, says the train is always late when it arrives -- and that would be true even if it arrived early.

'Only' is one of a small group of words sometimes called 'limiting modifiers' [Blinn]. These need positioning very carefully in a sentence, and alter the meaning of the sentence as their position is changed. 'Always' is a frequency adverb, In your sentence, (1) has the best placement, (2) is unidiomatic, while sentence-initial position (with a comma) is arguably acceptable, if in a literary register, and sentence-terminal position (with a comma or dash) adds emphasis or marks an afterthought.

I would call the second form poetic. If that is fitting, good. If not, it creates an unwelcome surprise, jarring or off. Better suited here: "He arrives always disheveled," when it's about the sloppiness, not the arrival.
